# Visual studio 2015, C# STAThread not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

STAThread is being ignored in VS 2015?
I have my main method with:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{...}
```

And i have a function which use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog and gives me the following exception:

**{"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."}**

CODE:

```
 try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
                {
                    InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                    Title = "Browse Text Files",

                    CheckFileExists = true,
                    CheckPathExists = true,

                    DefaultExt = "txt",
                    Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
                    FilterIndex = 2,
                    RestoreDirectory = true,

                    ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                    ShowReadOnly = true
                };

                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
```

Comment: If I just put your second code sample inside the `Main` brackets and run the code, it runs fine. You need to do more work to identify the piece *missing* from your question that would actually allow us to see what you're seeing. Obvious issues would be if you're creating other threads or creating `Task`s. Please check the page on creating a [mcve]

Comment: @Bogdan Scafariu, where do you put the above code, in the form_load or in the main method?

Comment: I'm using SAP Business One Framework, i cannot put that inside my main code.
Is in another class that gets called after some action happen, i debugged it and main class is STA but everything else is MTA.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

You can use OpenFileDialog in MTA using this 2 classes:

https://acharyarajasekhar.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/c-winforms-openfiledialog-with-mtathread/

Comment: ,I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.It will also help others to solve the similar issue.